# Sum over variable slices of numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have an m x n matrix stored as an ndarray. It's essentially a time series, with the times as rows (ordered) and the various different data streams as columns. My first goal is to identify points at which any of these columns crosses zero ("crossings"), which I accomplished using:

```
crossings = (np.diff(np.sign(original_matrix), axis=0) != 0)*1
```

Having done this, I now have a new (sparse) matrix with 1s at all crossings. What I need to do is take the sum of each slice of the original matrix that lies between two crossings.

Specifically, if a column has i crossings, I need to return the sum of values in the column since crossing i, divided by the sum of values in the column between crossing i-1 and crossing i-2. If there are no crossings, I need to return 0.

I've looked at boolean masks and sum.reduceat as solutions, and they seem fruitful. But I'm a bit stuck as to how to start.

**Update:**

Here's a simplified example (in reality the matrix would be more like 1000 x 1000)

```
#original matrix:

[[0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
 [0.5, -0.5, 0.5],
 [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
 [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
 [0.5, -0.5, 0.5],
 [0.5, -0.5, 0.5]
]

#crossings:
crossings = (np.diff(np.sign(original_matrix), axis=0) != 0)*1

[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]
]
```

So for the first column I need the sum of the last three rows [3:5] divided by the value of row [2]. For the second column I need the sum of rows [4:5] divided by the sum of rows [2:3]. For the third column, I return zero.

I realize I can get the indices of all the crossings using:

```
indices = np.transpose(np.nonzero(crossings))

array([[1, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 1]])
```

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to go from those indices to the sum.reduceat step.

Comment: Could you reproduce a minimal sample case and list out the expected outcome and if possible explain through it?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a job for [`numpy.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html).

Comment: @user2357112 yes - I was thinking some combo of numpy.where and numpy.add.reduceat

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? It is much more helpful if you leave a comment.